# Ping usage explanation

Tags: ping

When I type ping -h, I get a help with all possible flags.

However the first few characters are:
[-AaDdfnoQqRrv]

What this supposed to mean? as per my understanding there is no such flag as A or -a, at lest there is no explanation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention what Operating System you using.  Judging by the output i'm going to guess you're using some flavor of Linux.

The characters [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] are possible arguments for the Ping command.  Ping -h only gives a very basic help message.  I would recommend reading the manual (aka man page) you can find it by typing the following into your command line (on *nix based systems).

```
man ping
```

It will give you more information such as:

```
OPTIONS
   -a     Audible ping.

   -A     Adaptive ping. Interpacket interval adapts to round-trip time, so that effectively not more than one (or more,  if  preload  is
          set) unanswered probe is present in the network. Minimal interval is 200msec for not super-user.  On networks with low rtt this
          mode is essentially equivalent to flood mode.

   -b     Allow pinging a broadcast address.

   -B     Do not allow ping to change source address of probes.  The address is bound to one selected when ping starts.
```